# how to Checking if a number exists in telegram or not

Tags: python, api, telegram

I want to see if there is a phone number in telegram

To find out if there is a username or not, I used the following code
But it is not used for phone numbers

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def test(username):
url = 'https://t.me/' + username
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
   script.extract()
text = soup.get_text()
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
if text.splitlines()[3] =="@"+username:
   List_user_name.append("@"+username)
   print(len(List_user_name))
   return True
else:
   print(len(List_user_name))
   return False
```